# syntax error when using #ifdef in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to run the following code with and without the '-D DEBUG' gcc flag:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Defined");
#else
    printf("Not defined");
#endif

int main() 
{
}
```

The error I get is "debugtest.c:6:9: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant"

Comment: You can't have statements outside of functions.

Comment: If you want to see what the code looks like after running the preprocessor, run `gcc -E debugtest.c`. That will print a bunch of stuff to the screen from `#include <stdio.h>`, and then you will see that you have a lonesome `printf` before `main`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to `printf` has to be *inside* a function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Defined");
#else
    printf("Not defined");
#endif
    return 0;    
}
```